# failing k8s mongodb pod after some time - DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I'm running a kubernetes cluster (bare metal) with a mongodb (version 4, as my server cannot handle newer versions) replicaset (2 replicas), which is initially working, but from time to time (sometimes 24 hours, somtimes 10 days) one or more mongodb pods are failing.

```
Warning  BackOff  2m9s (x43454 over 6d13h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

The relevant part of the logs should be

```
DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/mongod.lock (Read-only file system). Ensure the user executing mongod is the owner of the lock file and has the appropriate permissions. Also make sure that another mongod instance is not already running on the /bitnami/mongodb/data/db directory
```

But I do not change anything and initially it is working. Also the second pod is currently running (but which will fail the next days).

I'm using longhorn (before I tried nfs) for the storage and I installed mongodb using bitnami helm chart with these values:

```
image:
  registry: docker.io
  repository: bitnami/mongodb
  digest: "sha256:916202d7af766dd88c2fff63bf711162c9d708ac7a3ffccd2aa812e3f03ae209" # tag: 4.4.15
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
architecture: replicaset
replicaCount: 2
updateStrategy:
  type: RollingUpdate
containerPorts:
  mongodb: 27017
auth:
  enabled: true
  rootUser: root
  rootPassword: "password"
  usernames: ["user"]
  passwords: ["userpass"]
  databases: ["db"]

service:
  portName: mongodb
  ports:
    mongodb: 27017

persistence:
  enabled: true
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  size: 8Gi

volumePermissions:
  enabled: true

livenessProbe:
  enabled: false
readinessProbe:
  enabled: false
```

**logs**

```
mongodb 21:25:05.55 INFO  ==> Advertised Hostname: mongodb-1.mongodb-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local
mongodb 21:25:05.55 INFO  ==> Advertised Port: 27017
mongodb 21:25:05.56 INFO  ==> Pod name doesn't match initial primary pod name, configuring node as a secondary
mongodb 21:25:05.59 
mongodb 21:25:05.59 Welcome to the Bitnami mongodb container
mongodb 21:25:05.60 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
mongodb 21:25:05.60 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
mongodb 21:25:05.60 
mongodb 21:25:05.60 INFO  ==> ** Starting MongoDB setup **
mongodb 21:25:05.64 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MONGODB_* env vars...
mongodb 21:25:05.78 INFO  ==> Initializing MongoDB...
mongodb 21:25:05.82 INFO  ==> Deploying MongoDB with persisted data...
mongodb 21:25:05.83 INFO  ==> Writing keyfile for replica set authentication...

mongodb 21:25:05.88 INFO  ==> ** MongoDB setup finished! **
mongodb 21:25:05.92 INFO  ==> ** Starting MongoDB **

{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:05.961+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:05.963+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:05.968+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:05.968+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:05.969+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.011+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/bitnami/mongodb/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"mongodb-1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.011+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.15","gitVersion":"bc17cf2c788c5dda2801a090ea79da5ff7d5fac9","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"debian10","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.012+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"PRETTY_NAME=\"Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)\"","version":"Kernel 5.15.0-48-generic"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.012+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/opt/bitnami/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf","net":{"bindIp":"*","ipv6":false,"port":27017,"unixDomainSocket":{"enabled":true,"pathPrefix":"/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp"}},"processManagement":{"fork":false,"pidFilePath":"/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb.pid"},"replication":{"enableMajorityReadConcern":true,"replSetName":"rs0"},"security":{"authorization":"disabled","keyFile":"/opt/bitnami/mongodb/conf/keyfile"},"setParameter":{"enableLocalhostAuthBypass":"true"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/bitnami/mongodb/data/db","directoryPerDB":false,"journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"logRotate":"reopen","path":"/opt/bitnami/mongodb/logs/mongodb.log","quiet":false,"verbosity":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.013+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/mongod.lock (Read-only file system). Ensure the user executing mongod is the owner of the lock file and has the appropriate permissions. Also make sure that another mongod instance is not already running on the /bitnami/mongodb/data/db directory"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.013+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784907, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the replica set node executor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.015+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-29T21:25:06.015+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

**Update**

I checked the syslog and before the the logs `Nov 14 23:07:17 k8s-worker2 kubelet[752]: E1114 23:07:17.749057     752 pod_workers.go:951] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"mongodb\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 10s restarting failed container=mongodb pod=mongodb-2_mongodb(314f2776-ced4-4ba3-b90b-f927dc079770)\"" pod="mongodb/mongodb-2" podUID=314f2776-ced4-4ba3-b90b-f927dc079770`

I find these logs:

```
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.341806] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#42 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=11s
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.341866] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#42 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.341891] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#42 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.341899] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#42 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 85 1f b8 00 00 40 00
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.341912] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 8724408 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.352012] Aborting journal on device sda-8.
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.354980] EXT4-fs error (device sda) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5726: Journal has aborted
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.355103] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#40 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=15s
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.357056] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#40 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.357061] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#40 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.357066] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#40 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 44 14 88 00 00 10 00
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.357068] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 4461704 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.357088] EXT4-fs error (device sda): ext4_dirty_inode:5922: inode #131080: comm mongod: mark_inode_dirty error
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.359566] EXT4-fs warning (device sda): ext4_end_bio:344: I/O error 7 writing to inode 131081 starting block 557715)
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.361432] EXT4-fs error (device sda) in ext4_dirty_inode:5923: Journal has aborted
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.362792] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 557713
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.364010] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 557714
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.365222] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#43 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=8s
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.365228] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#43 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.365230] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#43 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.365233] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#43 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 44 28 38 00 00 08 00
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.365234] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 4466744 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.367434] EXT4-fs warning (device sda): ext4_end_bio:344: I/O error 7 writing to inode 131083 starting block 558344)
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.367442] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 558343
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.368593] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#41 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=15s
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.368597] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#41 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.368599] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#41 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.368602] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#41 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 44 90 70 00 00 10 00
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.368604] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 4493424 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.370907] EXT4-fs warning (device sda): ext4_end_bio:344: I/O error 7 writing to inode 131081 starting block 561680)
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.370946] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#39 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=15s
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.370949] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#39 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.370952] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#39 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.370949] EXT4-fs error (device sda): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm kworker/u4:0: Detected aborted journal
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.370954] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#39 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 10 41 98 00 00 08 00
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.372081] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 1065368 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.374353] EXT4-fs warning (device sda): ext4_end_bio:344: I/O error 7 writing to inode 131080 starting block 133172)
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.374396] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 133171
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.388492] EXT4-fs error (device sda) in __ext4_new_inode:1136: Journal has aborted
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.390763] EXT4-fs error (device sda) in ext4_create:2786: Journal has aborted
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.391732] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#46 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.392941] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#46 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.392944] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#46 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.392948] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#46 CDB: Write(10) 2a 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.392950] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x23800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.395562] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.396945] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#45 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.396953] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#45 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.396955] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#45 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.396958] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#45 CDB: Write(10) 2a 08 00 84 00 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.396959] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 8650752 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x20800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.396930] EXT4-fs (sda): I/O error while writing superblock
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.399771] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1081344, lost sync page write
Nov 14 23:06:59 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413829.403897] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda-8.
Nov 14 23:07:01 k8s-worker2 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-d1c0f0dc3e024723707edfc12e023b98fb98f1be971177ecca5ac0cfdc91ab87-runc.w3zzIL.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:07:05 k8s-worker2 kubelet[752]: E1114 23:07:05.415798     752 dns.go:157] "Nameserver limits exceeded" err="Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted, the applied nameserver line is: 46.38.252.230 46.38.225.230 2a03:4000:0:1::e1e6"
Nov 14 23:07:06 k8s-worker2 kubelet[752]: E1114 23:07:06.412219     752 dns.go:157] "Nameserver limits exceeded" err="Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted, the applied nameserver line is: 46.38.252.230 46.38.225.230 2a03:4000:0:1::e1e6"
Nov 14 23:07:06 k8s-worker2 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-d1c0f0dc3e024723707edfc12e023b98fb98f1be971177ecca5ac0cfdc91ab87-runc.nK23K3.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:07:11 k8s-worker2 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-d1c0f0dc3e024723707edfc12e023b98fb98f1be971177ecca5ac0cfdc91ab87-runc.L5TkRU.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.411831] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#44 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=15s
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.411888] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#44 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.411898] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#44 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.411952] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#44 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 44 28 40 00 00 50 00
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.411965] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 4466752 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 10 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.419273] EXT4-fs warning (device sda): ext4_end_bio:344: I/O error 7 writing to inode 131083 starting block 558354)
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.430398] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#47 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=15s
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.430407] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#47 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.430409] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#47 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.430412] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#47 CDB: Write(10) 2a 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.430415] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x23800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.433686] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.436088] EXT4-fs (sda): I/O error while writing superblock
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.444291] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#32 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=14s
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.444300] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#32 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.444304] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#32 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.444308] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#32 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 41 01 18 00 00 08 00
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.444313] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 4260120 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.449491] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 532515, lost async page write
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.453591] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#33 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.453600] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#33 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.453603] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#33 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.453607] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] tag#33 CDB: Write(10) 2a 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.453610] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x23800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.459072] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.461189] EXT4-fs (sda): I/O error while writing superblock
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.464347] EXT4-fs (sda): Remounting filesystem read-only
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.466527] EXT4-fs (sda): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss!  (inode 131081, error -30)
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.470833] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 561678
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.473548] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 561679
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.477384] EXT4-fs (sda): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss!  (inode 131083, error -30)
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.482014] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 558344
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.484881] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 558345
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.487224] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 558346
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.488837] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 558347
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.490543] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 558348
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.492061] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 558349
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.493494] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 558350
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.494931] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 558351
```

Not sure, if this is really related to the problem.

Comment: A lot of the discussion, in both the question and [@R2D2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74424498/20042973), is about the inability of the `mongod` process to _start_. Presumably if things were running fine immediately prior to that, then the discussion should really be focused on what _failed_ and created the need to restart the environment. You should examine and/or provide the logs from immediately _before_ the failure to this question if we want to figure out that part of the puzzle.

Comment: @user20042973 I've added some logs before failing

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you see this error message:

```
"error":"DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/mongod.lock (Read-only file system)
```

It most probably mean that your mongodb pod did not shutted down gracefully and had no time to remove the mongod.lock file so when your pod was re-created in another k8s node the "new" mongod process cannot start because it is finding the previous mongod.lock file.

The easiest way to resolve the current availability issue is to scale up and  add immediately one more replicaSet member so the new member to init-sync  from the available good member:

```
helm upgrade mongodb bitnami/mongodb \
--set architecture=replicaset \
--set auth.replicaSetKey=myreplicasetkey \
--set auth.rootPassword=myrootpassword \
--set replicaCount=3
```

and elect again primary.

You can check if mongoDB replicaSet elected PRIMARY from mongo shell inside the pod with the command:

```
 rs.status()
```

For affected pod with the issue you can do as follow:

You can plan maitenance window and scale down ( scaling down stateFullset do not expect to automatically delete the [pvc/pv](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/) , but good to make backup just in case.

After you scale down you can start custom helper pod to mount the pv so you can remove the mongod.lock file:

Temporary pod that you will start to mount the affected dbPath  and remove the mongodb.lock file:

```
   kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: mongo-pvc-helper
   spec:
     securityContext:
       runAsUser: 0
    containers:
    - command:
       - sh
       - -c
       - while true ; do echo alive ; sleep 10 ; done
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: mongo-pvc-helper
    resources: {}
      securityContext:
        capabilities:
          drop:
            - ALL
   volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mongodata
        name: mongodata
   volumes:
     - name: mongodata
       persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: <your_faulty_pod_pvc_name>
  EOF
```

After you start the pod you can do:

```
kubectl exec mongo-pvc-helper -it sh
$ chown -R 0:0 /mongodata
$ rm /mongodata/mongod.lock
$ exit
```

Or you can complete wipe up the entire pv(if you prefer safely to init-sync entirely this member):

```
rm -rf /mongodata/*
```

And terminate the pod so you can finish the process:

```
 kubectl delete pod mongo-pvc-helper
```

And again scale-up:

```
  helm upgrade mongodb bitnami/mongodb \
  --set architecture=replicaset \
  --set auth.replicaSetKey=myreplicasetkey \
  --set auth.rootPassword=myrootpassword \
  --set replicaCount=2
```

Btw, good to have at least 3x  data members in replicaSet  for better redundancy to allow during single member down event election to keep still the PRIMARY up and running...

How to troubleshoot this further:

1. Ensure your pods have the terminationGracePeriod set (at least 10-20 sec) so it allow some time for the mongod process to flush data to storage and remove the mongod.lock file.
2. Depending from pod memory limits/requests , you can set some safer value for storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB (if not set it is allocating ~50% from memory  ).
3. Check the kubelet logs from node where pod was killed there maybe more details why pod was killed.

Comment: I added another one, so now I have prelicaCount = 3, but how do I find the reason why "mongodb pod did not shutted down gracefully"? Or do you believe it is just a lack of resources?

Comment: good to check if you have good delay for terminationGracePeriod ... , this is important for database statefullset since they need some time to flush data to storage  , could be also cpu or memory resources issue you will need to check in the k8s logs ...

Comment: I know it is basics, but how do I get access to the k8s logs, which could help me here to track the issue?

Comment: you can go to the kubernetes nodes and check /var/log/messages , journalctl -u kubelet , journalctl -u kubelet ... etc. , also if your logs are collected from mongo pods externally you may find the mesages eventually from the old pod ...

Comment: Only for better understanding: What is the difference of just deleting the failing pod, which gets recreated (and then works) or deleting the lock file as you described in your answer?

Comment: if you delete the pod it get re-created ( but mongod.lock file is not expected to be deleted since it is located in the pv that is not auto-deleted for pods having persistency  managed by statefullset's  )

Comment: I don't understand it: Added more resources, but the issue is still there. Also deleting the failing pod is working great, after that there is no lock issue. But that is of course no solution. My problem is, that I cannot identify the problem.

Comment: have you checked the kubelet logs from node that was holding the pods before the crash? also if deleting pod is fixing the problem that sounds like you pv's not persistent  and removed with the pods deletion , is that the case?

Comment: I've added some logs to the post before the pod is failing

Comment: It looks like disk that need to be replaced in k8s-worker2  before it is not too late  ...

Comment: This is the (new) third node/machine, I've added to get more resources. Before all other nodes had failing mongodb pods. The failing nodes occure on every node/machine. This logs are only the latest, which I found.

Comment: EXT4-fs (sda): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss!  -> sounds very scary to me , you better fix the infrastructure problems first before anything else ...

Comment: I already contacted the provider to check for the disks

Answer (score 0):

I think [@R2D2's extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74424498/20042973) makes some good points about how to recover from the situation. I very much agree with their recommendation to use 3 data bearing nodes which aligns with [fault tolerance considerations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/#consider-fault-tolerance). With the [additional logs you were able to add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334366/failing-k8s-mongodb-pod-after-some-time-dbpathinuse-unable-to-create-open-the?noredirect=1#comment131431944_74334366), I am arriving at the [same conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334366/failing-k8s-mongodb-pod-after-some-time-dbpathinuse-unable-to-create-open-the?noredirect=1#comment131437108_74424498) that your storage subsystem is the problem here which is going to be the actual cause of your MongoDB failing.

In your initial query the following log line was specifically highlighted:

`DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/mongod.lock (Read-only file system). Ensure the user executing mongod is the owner of the lock file and has the appropriate permissions. Also make sure that another mongod instance is not already running on the /bitnami/mongodb/data/db directory`

Specifically: `(Read-only file system)`. Now in the new logs you have provided the host itself is reporting:

```
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.459072] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.461189] EXT4-fs (sda): I/O error while writing superblock
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.464347] EXT4-fs (sda): Remounting filesystem read-only
Nov 14 23:07:14 k8s-worker2 kernel: [3413844.466527] EXT4-fs (sda): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss!  (inode 131081, error -30)
```

Specifically `Remounting filesystem to read-only`. If `mongod` is using any of these mount points for its operation then we would expect the system to no longer be able to function properly if it can no longer write to them. The database process itself may terminate, which is something the [storage node watchdog](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/monitoring/#storage-node-watchdog) could be configured to do (in subsequent versions).

In any case, the issues with the storage look quite serious, they include text like this: `failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss!` It seems imperative that you look into this further and resolve any issues as soon as possible.

Relatedly, you mentioned:

> I'm using longhorn (before I tried nfs) for the storage

The logs also suggest `EXT4-fs` is at play here. I think all of these have been known to have issues or otherwise be suboptimal for usage with MongoDB. From their [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/#kernel-and-file-systems):

> With the WiredTiger storage engine, using XFS is **strongly recommended** for data bearing nodes to avoid performance issues that may occur when using EXT4 with WiredTiger.

From [elsewhere on the same page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/#remote-filesystems--nfs-) (emphasis added):

> With the WiredTiger storage engine, WiredTiger objects may be stored on remote file systems if the remote file system conforms to ISO/IEC 9945-1:1996 (POSIX.1). **Because remote file systems are often slower than local file systems, using a remote file system for storage may degrade performance**.

I don't have any personal experience with Longhorn, but you can [see an example  here](https://github.com/longhorn/longhorn/issues/1909) where instability with that storage system caused the same `DBPathInUse` error that you observed. There are other reports of people having [nothing but problems with storage constantly detaching itself](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/obmlub/longhorn_for_k3_is_the_devil_of_storage/).

In short - instability with the storage subsystem is what is both causing the `mongod` process/pod to fail as well as preventing it from recovering. The problem is compounded by the fact that you only have 2 members in the replica set which provides no fault tolerance. Once you lose one member the other one will not be able to operate as a `PRIMARY` since there is no majority. Increasing the replica set to 3 members will at least provide fault tolerance of 1 node. The storage issues are a separate problem that should be pursued further via another question focused more on how that component is configured in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had something like that. That is always sad experience.

According to answer done by @R2D2. When you see `(Read-only file system)` in your logs - it can mean many things all not good. For instance when Linux starts file system is read-only, when everything is OK it is switched to read-write. That is not your case - so - just an example.

Please see that file system was marked as read-only due to io-errors. Looks like hard drive is corrupted. Check system, on which Kubernetes is running - fsck for Linux - like described [here](https://www.tecmint.com/check-linux-hard-disk-bad-sectors-bad-blocks/).

When drive is fixed restart Kubernetes - some data is lost, count on mongo complaining about data integrity... Nothing more than `mongod --repair` comes to my mind. Aaaand it can be that lock file should also be deleted before repair, but it should complain about it - like - "there is another instance", or "I can't set lock - file exists".

Besides that - use SMART monitoring, also mentioned later at the page.

Newer, faster, bigger drives are also more fragile. That is the price.

If you have backup... Yes I know - I've mentioned about my case - since then I have backup... Good luck!

Comment: I really don't understand that issue. fscheck / badblocks gives me `Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)`

Comment: https://longhorn.io/kb/troubleshooting-volume-readonly-or-io-error/ - maybe this post?